# How to activate lazy instantiation for all spring beans

Tags: spring

in a project there is several `applicationContext.xml` file. there isn't any lazy definition for defined beans. then all singleton scoped beans instantiate in runtime.
Oops. it's very bad for development phase. near 2 minutes take time that server startup. Now i will know is there any solution for active lazy-instantiate in spring. For example a configuration in web.xml that set bean default-lazy-init="true".

Comment: You have framed the question so nicely, hats off... :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement a custom BeanFactoryPostProcessor that sets lazy to true, e.g.:

```
public class BeanFactoryPostProcessorImpl implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

        for (String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName).setLazyInit(true);  
        }
    }
}
```

To get it working, all you need to do then is to add it to your application context as a standard bean:

> An ApplicationContext will detect any beans which are deployed into it
>   which implement the BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface, and
>   automatically use them as bean factory post-processors, at the
>   appropriate time. Nothing else needs to be done other than deploying
>   these post-processor in a similar fashion to any other bean.

Answer (score 0):

In `applicationContext.xml` files you can add `default-lazy-init` attribute with value `true` on the `<beans/>` element. See [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init).

Comment: i have many `applicationContext.xml` and this is not good that edit all of that. for example imagine you have 2000 `applicationcontext.xml`.then you will edit all of that?

Comment: So maybe implement `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and in `postProcessBeanFactory` do `for (String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName).setLazyInit(true);}`

Comment: thanks. but how can i register it. do i most just create a class that implement `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` or after that i should register it in web.xml or other configuration file. thanks.